# Laravel Eloquent Relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have define user relation with portfolio but it giving me null  my user model is

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function portfolio()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Portfolio');
    }

}
```

My portfolio model is

```
class Portfolio extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'ptitle', 'pdate','pedate','purl','languages','pdes','attachments'];

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function attachments()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Attachment');
    }
}
```

and I have define foreign key on migration my migration code is

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('portfolios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('ptitle');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                   ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I run the migration again. when i try get user portfolios it giving me null value i declare this on the top of my controller `use App\User;`  then i am finding the user by this command  `$user=User::find(1)` and finally i doing this `$user->portfolio()`  but it giving me null i am stuck in that from 2 to 3 hour please help me

Comment: yes i have one row in my table

Comment: table name is `portfolios`

Comment: i try this but it giving me error `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: No still giving me null .

Comment: Are u missing a **return** statement in your relation definitions?i.e. return $this->hasMany('App\Portfolio);

Answer (score 6):

you should return the relationship to get relation data

```
public function portfolio()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Portfolio');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic shortend example setup (used in the following example):

```
class User extends Model {
    public function portfolio()
    {
        //you missed the return
        return $this->hasMany('App\Portfolio');
    }

}
class Portfolio extends Model {
    public function user()
    {
        //you missed the return
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Assuming you have an user with ID 1 and a related portfolio entry:

```
$mUser = User::findOrFail(1); //Return User model
$mUserLazy = User::with('portfolio')->findOrFail(1); //Preload portfolio

$mPortfolioQueryBuilder = $mUser->portfolio(); //QueryBuilder

$aPortfolio = $mUser->portfolio; //Portfolio Collection
$aPortfolio = $mUserLazy->portfolio; //Portfolio Collection
$aPortfolio = $mPortfolioQueryBuilder->get(); //Portfolio Collection
```